# Pygame tutorial - tank with collision detection

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to Pygame and trying to learn about sprites and collision detection. I found some code and tried to add some functionality to it.

The basic idea is that I have a polygon which can be rotated in place. When the user presses SPACEBAR, the polygon fires a projectile which can bounce around the frame. If the projectile hits the polygon again, I would like to quite the program

First of all, here is the code

```
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        self.fire_from = (36, 20)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), ((0, 0), (32, 16), (0, 32)))
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()
        self.angle = 0
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(200, 200))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def update(self, events, dt):

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Projectile(self.fire_from, self.direction.normalize())
                    self.groups()[0].add(bullet)
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.angle += 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.angle -= 3

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 8))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('orange'), (4, 4), 4)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.direction = direction
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.max_bounce = 10

    def update(self, events, dt):

        #print(self.pos)
        # Bounding box of the screen
        screen_r = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()

        # where we would move next
        next_pos = self.pos + self.direction * dt

        # we hit a wall
        if not screen_r.contains(self.rect):

            # after 10 hits, destroy self
            self.max_bounce -= 1
            if self.max_bounce == 0:
                return self.kill()

            # horizontal reflection
            if next_pos.x > screen_r.right or next_pos.x < screen_r.left:
                self.direction.x *= -1

            # vertical reflection
            if next_pos.y > screen_r.bottom or next_pos.y < screen_r.top:
                self.direction.y *= -1

            # move after applying reflection
            next_pos = self.pos + self.direction * dt

        # set the new position
        self.pos = next_pos
        self.rect.center = self.pos

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    tank = Player()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    sprites.add(tank)
    #print(tank.groups()[0])
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    running = True
    while running:
        #print(tank.groups()[0])
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        sprites.update(events, dt)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        ## ALWAYS DETECTS A COLLISION, WHY?
        if len(tank.groups()[0])>1:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(tank, tank.groups()[0]):
                running = False

        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I gather here that the Player class (i.e. my tank) itself has a sprite groups, to which it adds each projectile as its fired. Furthermore, the projectile originates from within the rectangle for the polygon (hence it always initially collides)

I would like to only add the projectile to the sprite group if it has made at least 1 bounce, is that possible? Or... is there a better way to do this?

Any help or pointers please?

Thanks
Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tank` collides with itself, because it is a member of `tank.groups()[0]`:

> ```py
> if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(tank, tank.groups()[0]):
> ```

Add a *Group* that contains just the bullets:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def update(self, events, dt):

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Projectile(self.fire_from, self.direction.normalize())
                    self.groups()[0].add(bullet)
                    self.bullets.add(bullet)

        # [...]
```

Use this *Group* for the collision test:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while running:
        # [...]

        pygame.display.update()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(tank, tank.bullets):
            running = False

        dt = clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to do this earlier and kept getting confused between the different sprites group! But it makes sense, Player class holds it own group of sprites (i.e. bullets fired). But the question is, why do we need two sprite groups then in the player class?

Comment: @NullPointer You don't need them. However you want to draw all sprites with 1 call (`sprites.draw(screen)`).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thanks Rabbid, I think I'm getting the hang of this, much appreciated!